# Vagrant won't run startup-once files properly

Tags: shell, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, puphpet

I just created a new Vagrant box using puphpet and I have put a script file in /puphpet/startup-once/once.sh

I am trying to run commands like this to modify php.ini

```
sudo sed -i 's|;opcache.enable=0|opcache.enable=1|g' /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

And I am just getting errors like

> No such file or directoryd /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Then I connect using putty and I can see that the file is actually there. Why can't Vagrant run these files? I am running Virtual Box on Windows 8 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was having Windows style line endings. Converted the line endings to UNIX style and the scripts ran just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that for php.ini settings you should use the php section. Your changes will be overwritten by any future `$ vagrant provision` due to how the puppet php module handles settings.

Comment: Didn't know that. I guess I should put those settings to config files. But if I put them to execute-always shouldn't it be run on every provision and not on regular vagrant up or vagrant reload?